# When making Checkboxes using Datatables in PHP the value of checkbox is Always "on"

Tags: php, datatables

**Why is that it does not change its value when user clicks the checkbox also this check box cannot be clicked **

```
<div>
  <input id="list_check_flag" type="checkbox" name="response_template_fields[list_check_flag]"  >
  <label for="list_check_flag">List Check Flag</label>
</div>
```

**this is how i created a checkbox and if i use default checkbox its is clickable why is it not working in themed one**
[this is the Themed Checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Ozdq.png)

Comment: Probably because DataTables jams a bunch of style over it which blocks your input due to an overlay or something similar. Try devtools.

Answer (score 0):

Add class row on div element :

```
<div class="row">
  <input id="list_check_flag" type="checkbox" name="response_template_fields[list_check_flag]"  >
  <label for="list_check_flag">List Check Flag</label>
</div>
```

Put the css like as :

```
.row { Width :100%; Float:left; Position relative; }
```

Comment: Thanks alot i solved this problem log ago but had no time to check for the status of the question. thanks again for your asnwer

Comment: Most welcome.  I really appreciate your response on such small matter .

Comment: I was able to resolve above issue just like the suggestion you have given but well i solved that almost 20 days ago.

Comment: I think you did not see, I had replied just after 14 minutes after question asked.

Comment: I think you was inactive for long time.